# Does anybody use DjVu files in their production tools?

Tags: python, pdf, djvu

When it's about archiving and doc portability, it's all about PDF. I heard about [DjVu](http://djvu.org/) somes years ago, and it seems to be now mature enough for serious usages. The benefits seems to be a small size format and a fast open / read experience.

But I have absolutely no feedback on how good / bad it is in the real world :

- Is it technically hard to implement in traditional information management tools ?
- Is is worth learning / implementing solution to generate / parse it when you now PDF ?
- Is the final user feedback good when it comes to day to day use ?
- How do you manage exchanges with the external world (the one with a PDF only state of mind) ?
- As a programmer, what are the pro and cons ?
- And what would you use to convince your boss to (or not to) use DjVU ?
- And globally, what gain did you noticed after including DjVu in your workflow ?

Bonus question : do you know some good Python libs to hack some quick and dirty scripts as a begining ?

EDIT : doing some research, I ended up getting that Wikimedia use it to internally store its book collection but can't find any feedback about it. Anybody involved in that project around here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found DjVu to be ideal for image-intensive documents. I used to sell books of highly details maps, and those were always in DjVu. PDF however works really well; it's a standard, and -everybody- will be able to open it without installing additional software.

There's more info at:
http://print-driver.com/news/pdf-vs-djvu-i1909.html

Personally, I'd say until its graphic-rich documents, just stick to PDF.

Comment: At what cost (time, ressources, money) did you do this DjVu conversion other PDF ? Did you customers really found an added value in using DjVu ? Did they overchoose PDF is there was a choice ? Did they report trouble using DjVu ?

Comment: If I remember correctly ... this was a couple years back ...

My sources were in DjVu so I didn't have to make conversions to it. However, on a CD I would provide the DjVu files, a free DjVu program, as well as a file converted to PDF.

For the conversion, I used some command-line utility I found. The PDFs tended to be much larger in size, and much slower in rendering pages.